# Why is my loading scroll not working, is it the ajax call?

Tags: php, ajax, jquery-ui

The plan was to add a scroll w/a loading scroll within a page. 2 problems with that: My loading scroll does not work & I'm not sure if I should use an iframe to implement the loading scroll. Mainly because I have a jQuery sortable, droppable within my div and am not sure if I can drag outside a iframe. Any ideas would be appreciated

```
$(#win).scroll(function(){
//replaced window with #win, which is the id of the div containg database info
    if($(this)[0].scrollTop() == $(this)[0].height()- $(this).height()){

        //everytime we scroll we have this function activated
    //if statement is saying if we're at the bottom of the page
        //$('div#text').hide();
        $('div#loadMoreComments').show();
    //.show is showing the div above which has the loading animation

    $.ajax({
    url: "loadem.php?lastComment="+ $(".postedComment:last").attr("id"),
     //using get variable to say last comment is equal to + posted 
    //comment which is the last comment that's displayed &
    //that last comment has an id 
    success: function(html){
        if (html){
            $("#postedComment").append(html);
            //if we are at the bottom we will add comments to the page
            //and hide the animation
            $('div#loadMoreComments').hide();
            //$('div#text').show();


        }else{
            $('div#loadMoreComments').replaceWith("<div class='box'><center>Finished Loading</center></div>");
        //if theres no more to scroll then the finished loading will show
        }
    }
    });

    }
});
```

Comment: @webarto Thanks, but no that doesn't help it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if((jQuery(window).scrollTop()) > (jQuery(document).height() - jQuery(window).height()))
{
 ...... YOUR CODE IS HERE.....
}
```

this code will work the continuous pagination of your page. As far as I am concern it will have no effect on sortable, droppable cause you said it pagination div have covered all child element.

Hope this will help.

Comment: I think that would work if I wanted the whole page to be a loading scroll. I just want the info in my div to have a loading scroll. Any susggestions?

Comment: yes gotcha!! If you need infinite scroll in the particular div id replaceid then follow this link it may be help you and the one which you are looking for... 
[link]http://www.webdeveloperjuice.com/2010/02/24/create-infinte-scroll-effect-using-jquery-with-demo/[/link]
let me know if I missing something

Comment: The first link didn't take me to any loading scroll area and they didn't have a search bar so I could not search. The 2nd link was out of business

Comment: sorry for first link they redirected to the homepage But here is the working second link
http://fredwu.github.com/jquery-endless-scroll/

Comment: the first link is also working
http://www.webdeveloperjuice.com/2010/02/24/create-infinte-scroll-effect-using-jquery-with-demo/

see this...sorry for inconvenience because I am new to this site.

Feel free to ask any thing on the same.